# ReactJs: Why ref.current returns null when the component is rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a button inside a cart and I want give it an animation whenever the cart is opened. To target it I used useRef and tried to log in the console the result:

```
const checkoutBtnRef = useRef("null");

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(checkoutBtnRef.current);
    }, [cartOpen]);
```

The problem is that current is null when I open the cart and returns the actual button only when I close the cart, I expected it to be the opposite.
Any idea?

FULL COMPONENT CODE

```
export default function TopNav() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false);
    const checkoutBtnRef = useRef("null");

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(checkoutBtnRef.current);
    }, [cartOpen]);

    return (
        <>
            <Container maxWidth="xl">
                <div className={classes.root}>
                    <CardMedia
                        image="https://www.example.com"
                        className={classes.media}
                    />
                    <SearchBar placeholder="Search" className={classes.searchBar} />
                    <div className={classes.iconsContainer}>
                        <PersonIcon className={classes.icon} />
                        <FavoriteBorderIcon className={classes.icon} />
                        <Badge
                            invisible={false}
                            variant="dot"
                            color="error"
                            onClick={() => setCartOpen(true)}
                        >
                            <ShoppingBasketIcon className={classes.icon} />
                        </Badge>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Container>
            <Drawer
                classes={{
                    paper: classes.cart,
                }}
                anchor="right"
                open={cartOpen}
                transitionDuration={{ enter: 500, exit: 200 }}
                onClose={() => setCartOpen(false)}
            >
                <div className={classes.topCartContent}>
                    <Typography variant="h5">Cart</Typography>
                    <CloseIcon
                        className={classes.closeIcon}
                        onClick={() => setCartOpen(false)}
                    />
                </div>
                <Divider />
                <List>
                    <CartItem />
                </List>
                <Button
                    classes={{
                        root: classes.checkoutBtn,
                    }}
                    variant="outlined"
                    onClick={() => setCartOpen(false)}
                    ref={checkoutBtnRef}
                >
                    checkout
                </Button>
            </Drawer>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: full component code please.

Comment: @b3hr4d I posted the code for the full component! If you need any further detail I'll be more than happy to provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** :
your drawer has delay and your button didn't render yet so u cant see button on cartOpen change event and ...

so use this for storing and call your functions instead of useEffect.

```
 const checkoutBtnRef = (ref) => {
   console.log(ref);
   if (ref){
      // do ur staff here
   }
 };
```

If u need `useEffect` u can do it like this :

```
  const [btnRef, setBtnRef] = useState(null);

  const checkoutBtnRef = (ref) => {
    if (ref) setBtnRef(ref);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(btnRef);
  }, [btnRef]);
```

Old answer:

```js
const App = ()=>{
  const [cart,setCart]= React.useState(false);
  const [btnRef, setBtnRef] = React.useState(null);

  const checkoutBtnRef = (ref) => {
    if (ref) setBtnRef(ref);
    else setBtnRef(null)
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(btnRef);
  }, [btnRef]);
  
  const cartHandler = () => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
       setCart((prev) => !prev)
    },1000);
  };
 return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={cartHandler}>
     Cart
    </button>
    {cart && <button ref={checkoutBtnRef}>Check Out</button>}
   </React.Fragment>
 )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already tried this way and it make complete sense, but for some reason it doesn't work in my code. I posted the full component code, maybe you'll find what's wrong before I do :D

Comment: I understand the problem now but I didn't understand your solution, could you please refactor the first solution you gave me? I'm fairly new to React and I'm pretty confused at the moment

Comment: ok ill add delay on showing button u can get the idea.

Comment: In the code snippet after "If u need useEffect u can do it like this :" you never call the checkoutBtnRef function, so when will that function fire off?

Comment: when u make constant from a function after using constant it calls the function .

Comment: It works now! I just have to understand what you did and how you did it! Thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: @Zakaria Your welcome, I love helping people.

Comment: Your solution solved me many problems, but I still don't fully understand the logic behind it... the checkoutBtnRef function takes in a ref as parameter. When called inside the button (ref={checkoutBtnRef} what is the parameter passed inside it?

Comment: its because how `ref` props works in react , like mouseEvent have logic behind it. read this for more : https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html